# Printing out alias from sql query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to echo NumNotNull column not really sure how I tried with $row['NumNotNull'] didn't really work out

```
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
$champ_number = $result->num_rows;
$i = 1;
$champion = array();
$noofspellschamp = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    $champion[$i]=$row['champion'];

    $sql2 = "
    SELECT Passive, Q, W, E, R,
            ((Passive is not null) + (Q is not null) + (W is not null) + (E is not null) + (R is not null)
            ) as NumNotNull
    FROM champions
    WHERE Patch_No ='".$_GET['Patch_No']."' AND
          Champion = ".$row['champion']."";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    echo $result2;
    $noofspellschamp[$i] = $result2;                            

    $i+=1;
    //echo $champion[count($row)];
```

**EDIT**

```
var_dump($result2);
```

shows
boolean false
boolean false
by didn't work I meant it showed nothing

**EDIT3** No errors now thats what i get with var_dump

```
 object(mysqli_result)[2]
 public 'current_field' => null
 public 'field_count' => null
 public 'lengths' => null
 public 'num_rows' => null
 public 'type' => null
  object(mysqli_result)[5]
  public 'current_field' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'type' => null
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($result2)` shows?

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by "didn't really work"? Does it give an error message? If yes, then what? Also, the code you provided seems incomplete (there are syntax errors and I can't seem to find where `$row['NumNotNull']` is being done.

Comment: `var_dump($result2)` is `false` due to a failure of the query. Check `echo $conn->error;` to find out what failed.  Note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Since you are using mysqli, now is the time to learn to do it properly with [`prepare()/bind_param()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of placing that `$_GET` value directly into the query.

Comment: Minimal debugging would require you to `echo $sql2;` and show us what the query statement looks like with variables substituted before attempting to execute it with `$conn->query($sql2)`

Comment: new edit2 could you take a look? and by the way any good tutorials to learn about prepare/bind etc.? I'm new to thi smysqli world